# Binding expanders and listview to nested dictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a collection that looks like this:

```
ObservableDictionary<string, ObservableDictionary<string, SystemStatusItem>> ObservableColoServerStatus
```

I am working on creating a user control that I would like to bind as follows:

- Each key (string) key from the outer dictionary should dynamically create an expander.
- Inside that expander is a ListView/DataGrid/some control for displaying a collection of information
- Each line in the ListView/DataGrid or whatever will be composed of a combination of the (string) Key and a property from the (object)Value of the inner dictionary.

Ideally it should look and operate similarly to a TreeView however Expanders have been widely used through our UI so I would like to stick to this for consistency.

I am new to WPF and have done a bit of basic data binding before but the nature of this nested relationship is making this really difficult to wrap my head around

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, first lets asume that you ObservableDictionary is a collection of items that have a Key property and a Value property. What you want can be done in wpf using data templates, please see this code, try do it in this way:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ObservableColoServerStatus}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Expander Header="{Binding Key}">
                    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Value}">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
                </Expander>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

It is a list box, that has as ItemsSource your ObservableDictionary, then in the item template property you set the template that will use for representing all it itmes. In this case an expander, that have in the header the key a list box that take the elements from the Value of the first dictionary, and then you have set the template again. It is similar. Hope it works for you...

Comment: This looks really promising. I will test it out tonight to try and get it working, thanks for your time. I am also looking into splitting this problem apart into a few different classes so that I don't have to deal with nested dictionaries.